# Unit test Kafka Streams with MockedStreams fails with simple mapValues to convert in upper case

Tags: string, scala, unit-testing, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to unit test Kafka Stream with the [MockedStreams](https://github.com/jpzk/mockedstreams) library.

To test a simple example, I just want to **convert string into upper case**.

I try the code below :

```
import com.madewithtea.mockedstreams.MockedStreams
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes
import org.scalatest.{Matchers, WordSpec}

class mockedStreamsSpec extends WordSpec with Matchers {

  val input = Seq(("x", "foo"), ("y", "bar"))
  val exp = Seq(("x", "FOO"), ("y", "BAR"))

  "Put in upper case " should {
    "always return value in upper case" in {
      MockedStreams()
        .topology {
          builder =>
            builder.stream[String, String]("topic-in")
              .mapValues[String](_.toUpperCase())
              .to("topic-out")
        }
        .input("topic-in", Serdes.String(), Serdes.String(), input)
        .output("topic-out", Serdes.String(), Serdes.String(), exp.size) shouldEqual exp
    }
  }
}
```

I get an error avout `java.lang.String` :

```
[info] mockedStreamsSpec:
[info] Put in upper case
[info] - should always return value in upper case *** FAILED ***
  [info]   java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.lang.String
  [info]   at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMapValues$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMapValues.java:40)
[info]   at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:46)
[info]   at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsMetricsImpl.measureLatencyNs(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:208)
[info]   at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:124)
[info]   at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:85)
[info]   at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:80)
[info]   at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:216)
[info]   at org.apache.kafka.test.ProcessorTopologyTestDriver.process(ProcessorTopologyTestDriver.java:276)
[info]   at org.apache.kafka.test.ProcessorTopologyTestDriver.process(ProcessorTopologyTestDriver.java:315)
[info]   at com.madewithtea.mockedstreams.MockedStreams$Builder.$anonfun$produce$1(MockedStreams.scala:110)
```

It seems weird, because Scala String and Java String should be identical.

Comment: Just a hint: Kafka 1.1 was release and it contains a `kafka-streams-test-utils` package for unit testing. Might be worth to check out: https://kafka.apache.org/11/documentation/streams/developer-guide/testing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used this MockedStreams library but the exception "[B cannot be cast to java.lang.String" means a byte array is being cast to a String. I suggest you try using the variant of builder.stream() method (inside the topology) that lets you explicitly specify the Serdes to use, as it seams the ones given to the input() method are not being used. I guess those are only used to serialize the test data onto the stream.

Comment: Thanks ! Indeed the solution was to add 'Produced with' and 'Consumed with' : ```builder.stream[String, String]("topic-in",
              Consumed.`with`(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()))``` and ```.to("topic-out",
                Produced.`with`(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()))```